# Loop through multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

How can i loop through the below multidimensional array?

I am creating the array like this:

```
var _cQueue = [[]];
```

And adding items like this:

```
var valueToPush = new Array();
valueToPush['unique_email@gmail.com'] = '1234567';
_cQueue.push(valueToPush);
```

I want to loop through all different email adresses that are added, and then each random string associated with that email

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909218/placing-a-multi-dimensional-array-into-javascript-from-php-using-json ... see from this answer and you should get it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should not add elements to arrays by key, but to objects. Which means your global object should be build as :

```
var _cQueue = [];
var valueToPush = {}; // this isn't an array but a js object used as map
valueToPush['unique_email@gmail.com'] = '1234567';
_cQueue.push(valueToPush);
```

Then, you iterate using two kinds of loops :

```
for (var i=0; i<_cQueue.length; i++) { // iterate on the array
   var obj = _cQueue[i];
   for (var key in obj) { // iterate on object properties
      var value = obj[key];
      console.log(value);
   }
}
```

See MDN's excellent [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

---

If you want to find the email associated to an id, you can do two things :

1) loop until you find it :

```
function find(id) {
    for (var i=0; i<_cQueue.length; i++) { // iterate on the array
       var obj = _cQueue[i];
       for (var key in obj) { // iterate on object properties
          var value = obj[key];
          if (value==id) return key;
       }
    }
}
```

2) put all the ids in a map so that it can be found faster :

```
   var bigMap = {};
   for (var i=0; i<_cQueue.length; i++) { // iterate on the array
       var obj = _cQueue[i];
       for (var key in obj) { // iterate on object properties
          bigMap[obj[key]] = key; // maps the id to the email
       }
    }
    function find(id) {
        return bigMap[id];
    }
```

Comment: How can i get the email associated with the ID using the above?

Comment: _cQueue.length is undefined since it's object

Comment: @Alosyius If you have to do frequent searches for an id, you'd better not loop each time. See the last code I added.

Comment: Btw, how could i find all specific numbers for a specific email adress?

Comment: Well, you could instantiate an empty array, do the iteration and each time the email is your specific address push your email address to the array you created.

Answer (score -1):

use for-in to both levels:

```
for(var val in _cQueue){
var obj = _cQueue[val];
   for(var val1 in obj){
    alert('key(email):' + val1 + '\nValue:' + obj[val1]);
   }
}
```